# How do I get the search results to display more than 2 options?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress

I currently have this code to filter out text div's upon search.

I've added 4 items named "Hot Dog" with completely different SKU's, when searched it only displays 2 items. How do I get all of the items to display?

The JS script works as it filters out the divs upon search but I can't seem to figure out why it only displays 2 items:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $btns = $('.btn').click(function() {
    if (this.id == 'all') {
      $('#parent > div').fadeIn(450);
    } else {
      var $el = $('.' + this.id).fadeIn(450);
      $('#parent > div').not($el).hide();
    }
    $btns.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  })

  var $search = $("#search").on('input', function() {
    $btns.removeClass('active');
    var matcher = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'gi');
    $('.box').show().not(function() {
      return matcher.test($(this).find('.name, .sku').text())
    }).hide();
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="text" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search product by name or sku">
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="row" id="parent">
  <div class="col-md-2 box drink">
    <center>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
      <p class="name">Pepsi </p>
      <p class="sku">D-1251</p>
      <p>$ 2,410</p>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 box drink">
    <center>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
      <p class="name">Cocacola </p>
      <p class="sku">D-1314</p>
      <p>$ 2,410</p>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 box drink">
    <center>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
      <p class="name">Mountien Dwe </p>
      <p class="sku">D-458</p>
      <p>$ 2,410</p>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 box food">
    <center>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
      <p class="name">Burger </p>
      <p class="sku">F-125</p>
      <p>$ 2,410</p>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 box food">
    <center>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
      <p class="name">Hot Dog </p>
      <p class="sku">F-7412</p>
      <p>$ 2,410</p>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 box food">
    <center>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
      <p class="name">Hot Dog 2</p>
      <p class="sku">F-74122</p>
      <p>$ 2,4103</p>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 box food">
    <center>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
      <p class="name">Hot Dog 2233</p>
      <p class="sku">F-74112</p>
      <p>$ 2,4103</p>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To correct the issue you need to define the `RegExp` object within each iteration of the loop:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $btns = $('.btn').click(function() {
    if (this.id == 'all') {
      $('#parent > div').fadeIn(450);
    } else {
      var $el = $('.' + this.id).fadeIn(450);
      $('#parent > div').not($el).hide();
    }
    $btns.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  })

  var $search = $("#search").on('input', function() {
    $btns.removeClass('active');
    let value = $(this).val();

    $('.box').show().not(function() {
      return new RegExp(value, 'gi').test($(this).find('.name, .sku').text());
    }).hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="text" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search product by name or sku">
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="row" id="parent">
  <div class="col-md-2 box drink">
    <center>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
      <p class="name">Pepsi </p>
      <p class="sku">D-1251</p>
      <p>$ 2,410</p>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 box drink">
    <center>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
      <p class="name">Cocacola </p>
      <p class="sku">D-1314</p>
      <p>$ 2,410</p>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 box drink">
    <center>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
      <p class="name">Mountien Dwe </p>
      <p class="sku">D-458</p>
      <p>$ 2,410</p>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 box food">
    <center>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
      <p class="name">Burger </p>
      <p class="sku">F-125</p>
      <p>$ 2,410</p>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 box food">
    <center>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
      <p class="name">Hot Dog </p>
      <p class="sku">F-7412</p>
      <p>$ 2,410</p>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 box food">
    <center>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
      <p class="name">Hot Dog 2</p>
      <p class="sku">F-74122</p>
      <p>$ 2,4105</p>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 box food">
    <center>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
      <p class="name">Hot Dog 2233</p>
      <p class="sku">F-74112</p>
      <p>$ 2,4103</p>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Rory, this works. Do you think there's a possible way to add a button to the search bar and have it only filter the divs on click?

Comment: Sure. Wrap the input in a `form` with a submit button and change the event handlers around: https://jsfiddle.net/3r495kbc/

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks, Rory. I've created a new fiddle where I then have 2 separate inputs, dividing the 'name' & 'sku' into 2 separate inputs along with the search button but does not seem to work. https://jsfiddle.net/zuh_fiddl3/1eo5q2nf/1/

Comment: The issue there is because you need to change the regex as you're looking for two separate words instead of a single one. I'd suggest researching regex word boundaries, or starting a new question if you still have issues with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to get away from using regex you can do a quick search using [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes). Also, you have a small typo on `Dwe` in Mountain Dew.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $search = $("#search").on('input', function() {
    //$btns.removeClass('active');
    const searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('.box').filter((_, elem) => !$(elem).find(".name").text().toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)).hide()
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="text" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search product by name or sku">
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="row" id="parent">
  <div class="col-md-2 box drink">
    <center>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
      <p class="name">Pepsi </p>
      <p class="sku">D-1251</p>
      <p>$ 2,410</p>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 box drink">
    <center>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
      <p class="name">Cocacola </p>
      <p class="sku">D-1314</p>
      <p>$ 2,410</p>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 box drink">
    <center>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
      <p class="name">Mountien Dwe </p>
      <p class="sku">D-458</p>
      <p>$ 2,410</p>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 box food">
    <center>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
      <p class="name">Burger </p>
      <p class="sku">F-125</p>
      <p>$ 2,410</p>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 box food">
    <center>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
      <p class="name">Hot Dog </p>
      <p class="sku">F-7412</p>
      <p>$ 2,410</p>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 box food">
    <center>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
      <p class="name">Hot Dog 2</p>
      <p class="sku">F-74122</p>
      <p>$ 2,4103</p>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 box food">
    <center>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
      <p class="name">Hot Dog 2233</p>
      <p class="sku">F-74112</p>
      <p>$ 2,4103</p>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```